# An existing Uber app has lost all of its authorizations

Tags: uber-api

Users are getting an unauthorized message when the app accesses the Uber API.  This was all working earlier, and the app had all of the appropriate authorizations enabled in the dashboard.  Users login via the Uber app and authorize my app for access, but something's broken, and my first clue is the authorizations are no longer checked in the dashboard.  How did this happen and what can be done to fix it?

More details:

This is an iOS app and uses the Server Token to auth the app in API calls.  On the Uber dashboard the app had been authorized for several scopes, including full access to the ride scope.  When I look at the dashboard now, none of the scopes are checked.  What happened?

When a user tries to login - using the native login process (login button -> Uber), the Uber app immediately bounces back to our app (not even asking for login or showing the auth options) and shows a message about the app not being authorized.

Answer (score 0):

Your application may use Server Token authentication when accessing resources that are not specific to a user. This will allow you request only Time and Price estimates without requiring a user to log in. For any other API calls please follow our [OAuth 2.0](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/guides/authentication/introduction#oauth-20) or [iOS SDK](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/api/ios#configure-sdk-credentials)  authentication documentation.

Comment: I'm not really following what you say to do.  This is an iOS app and it's using the Server Token to make API calls - some direct and some using the RidesClient SDK.  Are you saying our Server Token expired?  We have tried fresh app installs, deleting the auth token and re-authoring the app, etc.  What concerns me most is that none of the app authorizations are checked in the dashboard.  What happened there?

Comment: Based on the initial info you supplied we give you one of the reasons why authentication is not working. Please provide full details of the problem, how did you try to authenticate and what API calls you made - so we can try to help you.

Comment: Yes, follow all of that - as noted in more details, the app uses native login to authenticate. The app was working, then stopped. The problem as noted in the question is that the scopes were no longer checked in the Uber dashboard.  We didn't uncheck them.  The result is the behavior we described - a user gets bounced back from the Uber app. I have someone from Uber on Twitter helping me.